# How to get response from iframe login into angular app

Tags: angular

I am setting up a third party login page in my angular 8 application.

I am working on 3rd party identity management integration into angular 8 apps. 
I am using Iframe to load 3rd party login page and able to login with credentials but how do I get a response from Iframe once I logged in .. because I need to show parent page once logged in. Thanks for advance.

I Tried it in the google but I did not find any solution... Is it the right way to do it or any other way? I am using angular 8 for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

```
window.parent.someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow(data);
//someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow is defined in electron app/ other iframe loaded //app
```

## .html

```
 <iframe id="" class="" height="100%" width="100%" style="border: 0;" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

## DomSanitizerPipe.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'domSanitizer'
})
export class DomSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(htmlString: string, args?: any): any {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
    }

}
```

## .ts

```
   constructor(
        public sanitizer:DomSanitizer
    ) { 
        this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://.....');
    }
```

## 2) get into the "DOM" of this loaded page, from parent component.

## .ts

```
window.parent.someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow(data);

//someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow is defined in electron app/ other iframe loaded //app
```

## iframe app

```
someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow (){
 // I am inside iframe app
}
```

## 3) calling method defined in component.ts from iframe app

## index.html

```
     <app-root></app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//updateFromDevice is called from iframe
            function updateFromDevice(data) {
                window['componentRef'].zone.run(() => {
                    window['componentRef'].component.updateFromIframe(data);
                });
            }
        </script>
```

## app.component.ts

```
 constructor(
        private zone: NgZone,
    ) {
        window['componentRef'] = {
            zone: this.zone,
            componentFn: (value) => this.updateFromIframe(value),
            component: this
        };
    }

  updateFromIframe(data) {}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But I dont have any control over the ifram app.. its just URL i am loading using ifram. I dont know where to specify this line window.parent.someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow(data);

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: how do I get a response from Iframe once I logged in? (2) get into the "DOM" of this loaded page, from parent component as window.parent.someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow(data); where someMethodDefinedInOpenWindow() method is defined inside iframe app.

Comment: I can not define any methods inside ifram app Becasue its just 3rd party URL. But once logged in they are saving token in local storage.. I wanna get that token to call other services in my main app.